# How to a dependency to my custom cocoapod?

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm creating a cocoapods which is doing some crypto stuff. I've a dependency in my podspec file (mean another cocoapods library).

My spec file is:

```
   ...
      s.dependency 'BigInt', '~> 1.3.0'
   end
```

And it can pass pod verification successfully but I cannot see this library in my class, I cannot import! How I can import this library without any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the idea! While working on your cocoapod you need to create another test project with your cocoapod's dependencies. So you won't see any error.

Also when you add your cocoapods to a project, It'll download automatically its dependency and add them to pods project's frameworks.